# Quotient module of module generated by integral basis

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-number-theory

Let $K/\mathbb{Q}$ be a number field of degree $n$ and $\mathcal O_K$ be its ring of integers. Let $\{v_i \}_{1\leq i\leq n}\subseteq \mathcal{O}_K$ be a basis of $K$. Let $M\subseteq \mathcal{O}_K$ be the abelian group generated by $\{v_i \}$ over $\mathbb{Z}$. Let $\{w_i \}$ be the dual basis with respect to $\text{Tr}_{K/\mathbb{Q}}$, and $M'$ generated by $\{w_i \}$ over $\mathbb{Z}$. We then have
$$M'=\{x\in K|\text{Tr}_{K/\mathbb{Q}}(xy)\in\mathbb{Z},\forall y\in M \}   $$
I want to show that $M'/M$ is finite with cardinality |Disc$(v_1,\dots,v_n)$|. Could anyone please help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As $M \subseteq M'$ and they are both finitely generated submodules of $K$ from a well-known identity we have that $\text{disc}(M) = [M':M]^2 \cdot \text{disc}(M')$. If you are not familiar with this identity you can find a proof of it under Proposition $2.12$ in Neukirch's "Algebraic Number Theory". In fact, I'm pretty sure most of algebraic number theory textbooks include it. So from this we have that:

$$[M':M]^2 = \left| \frac{\text{disc}(M)}{\text{disc}(M')} \right|$$

As $\text{disc}(M) = |\text{disc}(v_1,\dots,v_n)|$, it remains to prove that $\text{disc}(M')^{-1} = |\text{disc}(v_1,\dots,v_n)|^{-1}$. This follows almost immediately from the duality of the basis. Indeed

$$1 = (\det I)^2 = \det (\text{Tr}(v_iw_j))^2 = \det\left(\sum_k (\sigma_kv_i)(\sigma_kw_j)\right)^2 \\ = \det(\sigma_kv_i)^2 \cdot \det(\sigma_kw_j)^2 = \text{disc}(M) \cdot \text{disc}(M') $$